# Is different subscriber working like different thread?

Tags: ros, c++, thread, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example, I want to subscribe to 2 topics ("/scan" and "/odometry")

the "/scan" frequency is 10Hz, while the "/odometry" frequency is 50Hz.

But in my program, the `scanCallBack` function is computational heavy, so it cannot process as fast as the "/scan".

the `odomCallBack` function is not that heavy, so it has the potential to process like 50Hz.

I expected them to work separately, but when I try print out time, I found the `odomCallBack` function now has the same frequency as the `scanCallBack` function, at 6Hz.

So does it mean the subscribers can affect each other, instead of working separately like different threads?

By the way, how can I fix this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262550/is-different-subscriber-working-like-different-thread?/) by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2017-05-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-05-25**:
Why not use two nodes?

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-05-26**:
@jayess I need to do sensor fusion. So I need to put them in one program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default roscpp executes your subscriber callbacks single-threaded, which is what you're observing.

You can process callbacks on multiple threads, or assign specific threads to callbacks by using a MultiThreadedSpinner, AsyncSpinner,  CallbackQueue or various combinations of these as described in http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-05-26**:
Thanks, it works!